# Getting last described cell in line

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to get the last described cell with  in a row with code. So if I'm positioned in A14 and my last described cell A4 contains `Hello` I want that A14 also contains `Hello`. I wont care about B4 and so on. If I'm positioned in B13 I just care about the B-Row and so on. Unfortunately I have no idea of VBA so I prefer a non-VBA solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that perhaps:

```
=LOOKUP("zzz",A1:A13)
```

Or using `MATCH()`:

```
=INDEX(A1:A13,MATCH("zzz",A1:A13))
```

Or using `VLOOKUP()`:

```
=VLOOKUP("zzz",A1:A13,1)
```

Comment: I don't look for a specific value, I'm looking for just a value int the most left cell of my position. Does it work too?

Comment: @Lithilion Yep, all of those functions are looking for 'loose' matches, and that has the effect of getting the last text value by default. If you need to get numbers, it'll be a large number instead of `"zzz"`, maybe `2^99`.